# Search receiver ID by the USER ID first and locate the data by the receiver ID

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakePHP 1.26.
I got a simple Table with some data in my localhost Database:

```
user_id | message    | receiver_id
-----------------------------
1       | helloworld | 12
2       | hi there   | 12
```

Let say the system now received the $userid from a user.
The user only got the user ID. He wants to search all the message received by a specific Receiver
Here is my code for the case mentioned above:

```
$receiverID=$this->user->read('receiver_id', $userid); // find the receiver ID
$data=$this->user->findByreceiver_id($receiverID); //then retrieve data by the receiver ID
debug($data);
```

The code isn't neat and looks clumsy.
I am not sure if there is any best way to do it in this case.

Please advise.

Comment: Is this returning the result set you expect?

Comment: @Jason. Sorry, I made a mistake in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, you could do:

```
$data = $this->User->findByreceiver_id( $this->User->read( 'receiver_id', $userid ) );
```

This assumes that your code above works as expected.

Or you could hide some of that syntax in the model.  Write a Model::find_by_receiver( $user_id ) and it would contain the actual find call, and return it.  Seems a little overkill on the wrappers, though.  But it will make your controller *appear* more neat.

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://book.cakephp.org/view/851/Multiple-relations-to-the-same-model) from the cookbook may help.